# Magento 2.2 : uiComponent Form : show images in a field

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, adminform

I would like to show images in a field without having uploader button. I have images name in the DB column. How could i use a renderer for the field or any other way to do this?

Comment: Please provide the code that you use to create form field

Comment: @NeroPhung: just added new fieldset for the images field.
`<fieldset name="images">
        <settings>
            <label>Product Images</label>
        </settings>
    </fieldset>`
not sure how to add field to get this accomplished.